# Popping sole member of stack

Tags: c, stack

I built a stack structure in C using a doubly-linked list and I'm running into a segfault when popping the last element of the list. Here's the pop method and some relevant globals:

```
typedef struct node {

    int value;
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;

} node;

node *head = NULL;
node *tail = NULL;
int stackSize = 0;

int removeFromStack(){
    node *tempNode = head;

    if(stackSize <= 0){
        emptyStackError();
    }

    int val = head->value;

    if(stackSize == 1){
        head = NULL; //Segfaults here
        tail = NULL;
    }

    else{
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = NULL;
    }

    free(tempNode);
    stackSize--;
    return val;
}
```

So clearly I'm not supposed to be just setting the head and tail to null. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: with a stack size of one both your head and tail should be equal to the single object on the stack

Comment: @brendanmorrison : It's one *before* the pop, so this looks OK.

Comment: @brendanmorrison: The clause that sets `head` and `tail` to `NULL` is in an `if` that checks `stackSize` before it is decremented to indicate the last object has been removed. That code is making the list empty, not setting it to have one object.

Comment: @user1874204: You should show a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org) and sample input that reproduces the problem. The statement `head = NULL;` is not likely to cause a segment fault; you may have been mislead about the precise location of the fault by the debugger or other tool.

Comment: The code here looks OK at first glance. The only problem I can see is if you pop when the stack is empty :  emptyStackError() gets called, but the function then continues to run...

Comment: Setting a global pointer to NULL doesn't segfault. Most likely it fails somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not likely to be where you said. You just assign a value to a pointer. My guess is that it is coming from two lines above.

Before:

```
int val = head->value;
```

Please add:

```
assert(head != NULL && "Oops, the counter is messed up");
```

And try to run your code again.

If the assert fires, track all usage of `stackSize`. If it does not, it doesn't necessarily mean that the pointer is not random, or points on de-allocated space. Comment everything but `head->value` in this function. Then try to create a list, push one element, then try call `removeFromStack`. Then try push two elements, pop one and try `removeFromStack` again.

My guess is your counter get corrupted somewhere in another function.